# How to tfidfvectorizer on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to use sklearn TFIdfVectorizer on panda after I split the training and testing data

Here's code for split the data :

```
train = data_df
    train_df,test_df= train_test_split(train,test_size=0.2)
```

and i tried use the TFIdfVectorizer function :

```
start = time.clock()
vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))
train_df = vect.fit_transform(train_df)
test_df = vect.transform(test_df)

print (time.clock()-start)
```

but it came out error like this :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-3588531e9fc6> in <module>
      3 vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))
      4 #converting traning features into numeric vector
----> 5 train_df = vect.fit_transform(train_df)
      6 #converting training labels into numeric vector
      7 test_df = vect.transform(test_df)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1218 
   1219         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
-> 1220                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1221 
   1222         if self.binary:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
   1148             vocabulary = dict(vocabulary)
   1149             if not vocabulary:
-> 1150                 raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only"
   1151                                  " contain stop words")
   1152 

ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

is there something that i miss ? or any solution to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your records may contain single string. Try to convert them to list or set the minimum document frequency to 1. Do have a look at below given link which produce your desired result:

[ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222695/valueerror-empty-vocabulary-perhaps-the-documents-only-contain-stop-words)